# Particle Tracking by coordinates from txt file

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have some particle track data from an OpenFoam simulation.
The data looks like this:

```
0.005 0.00223546 1.52096e-09 0.00503396
0.01 0.00220894 3.92829e-09 0.0101636
0.015 0.00218103 5.37107e-09 0.0154245
.....
```

First row is time, then x, y ,z coordinates.
In my folder, I have a file for every tracked particle.

I would like to calculate the velocity and the displacement for each particle in each timestep.

It would be nice to enter the position data in a way like particle[1].time[0.01].

Is there already a python tool for that kind of problem? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you provide a larger dataset? Perhaps in a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com)? (you know, you _should_ have a GitHub account anyway... ;o)

Comment: GitHub done... thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You "almost" don't need numpy for that. I created a simple class hierarchy with some initial methods. You could improve from that if you like the approach. Note that I am creating from a string, you should use `for line in file` instead of the `string.split` way.

```
import numpy

class Track(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.trackpoints = []

    def AddTrackpoint(self, line):
        tpt = self.Trackpoint(line)
        if self.trackpoints and tpt.t < self.trackpoints[-1].t:
            raise ValueError("timestamps should be in ascending order")
        self.trackpoints.append(tpt)
        return tpt

    def length(self):
        pairs = zip(self.trackpoints[:-1], self.trackpoints[1:])
        dists = map(self.distance, pairs)
        result = sum(dists)
        print result

    def distance(self, points):
        p1, p2 = points
        return numpy.sqrt(sum((p2.pos - p1.pos)**2)) # only convenient use of numpy so far

    class Trackpoint(object):
        def __init__(self, line):
            t, x, y, z = line.split(' ')
            self.t = t
            self.pos = numpy.array((x,y,z), dtype=float)


entries = """
0.005 0.00223546 1.52096e-09 0.00503396
0.01 0.00220894 3.92829e-09 0.0101636
0.015 0.00218103 5.37107e-09 0.0154245
""".strip()


lines = entries.split("\n")

track = Track()

for line in lines:
    track.AddTrackpoint(line)

print track.length()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have regular time steps, you can use a pandas dataframe to find the difference

```
import pandas as pd

dt = .005 #or whatever time difference you have

df = pd.read_csv(<a bunch of stuff indicating how to read the file>)
df['v_x'] = df.diff(<the x colum>)
df['v_x'] = df['v_x']/dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Individual files would be easily loaded with something like:

```
import numpy as np
t, x, y, z = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=' ', unpack=True)
```

Now there is an issue as you would like to index particule position with time, whereas Numpy will only accept integers as indices.

edit: in Python you could make "position" a dictionary so that you can index it with a float, or anything else. But now that comes down to the amount of data you have, and what you want to do with it. Because dictionaries will be less efficient than Numpy arrays for anything a little more 'advanced' than just picking position at time t.